# load large amount of data in android spinner blocks UI

Tags: android, android-spinner, large-data

I am working on an `Android app` project in one of `activities` I have a `spinner` that I used

https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner

as I wanted my `spinner` can be filtered by item name and it works perfect.

But I want to load a very large amount of items in my `spinner` (about 70000 items). My spinner can load this amount but it takes too long till my UI respond.

I know there are practices that suggest to use `paging` and other possible resolutions but I can not use them at this moment and also I tried to use a `AsyncTask` to make this process a `background` process but it doesn't work either.

Here is my code to load items in spinner by the way (ArrayList goods could contain 70000 items) :

```
private void prepareProductsSpinner() {
    productsSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerProduct);

    ArrayList<Good> goods = (ArrayList<Good>) Good.listAll(Good.class);

    //fill data in spinner
    ArrayAdapter<Good> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AddEditAssetTakingItemActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, goods);
    productsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    productsSpinner.setTitle("Choose an item");
    productsSpinner.setPositiveButton("Select");
}
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: How did you solved it?

Comment: @b-developer I used another activity that had a recycler view to show all products, when the user selects an item I've returned the id for that and load that item into that spinner.

Answer (score 2):

You can display arraylist in spinner recycleview. The `RecyclerView` is much more powerful, flexible. it doesn't freezes the UI. It supports the use Viewholder pattern and can contains 100k+ rows it runs very smooth.
[Spinner with recylerview.](https://androidreality.blogspot.com/2017/02/spinner-in-recyclerview-android.html)

Comment: Ok I will try that and let you know .

Comment: The suggested solution didn't work for me . The problem is in the mechanism for loading items in a single Spinner not in adding multiple spinner to a Activity.